# jQuery mobile - how to connect between <a href> and the click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm a newbie to jQuery and jQuery mobile.

I followed a few samples and documentations and created the following code:

```
function initListByUrl(id, requestUrl) {
$.ajax({
    url: requestUrl,
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var items = []
        $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
                items.push('<li id="cat_li_'+i+'"><a href="#places">' + elem.name + '</a></li>');
            });
        id.html(items).listview('refresh');
    }

});
}


$(document).on("click", '[id^=cat_li]', function(event, ui) {
  console.log(3);
 })
```

I need to have the elem event from the $.ajax available in the context of the click event

This is because the elem object holds a field that is relevent when the item is clicked.

How should I do it?

EDIT

just to clarify.

the initListByUrl functions is called in document-ready. It builds a list view by the retrieved json object which contains an array.

if I had elem in the context of the on-click event I would have done something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id^=cat_li]', function(event, ui) {
    call_some_function(elem.someField);
 })
```

My issue is how do I have the appropriate elem object in the scope of the on-click event?

### EDIT 2

This is my full code:

```
var stack = []

var site_url = 'http://localhost:3000';
$(function() {


    initCategoriesList();

    $("#places").on('pageinit', function() {
        var category = stack.pop();
        initPlacesList(category);
    });

    $("#place").on('pageinit', function() {

    });


});


function initCategoriesList(id, requestUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: site_url + '/categories',
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var items = []
            $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
                items.push('<li id="cat_li_'+i+'"><a href="#places">' + elem.name + '</a></li>');
            });
            $("#categories_ul").html(items).listview('refresh');
        }

    });
}

function initPlacesList(category_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: site_url + '/business_places/category/' + category_id,
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var items = []
            $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
                items.push('<li id="place_li_'+i+'"><a href="#place">' + elem.name + '</a></li>');
                $("#places_ul").html(items).listview('refresh');
                var element = $("#place_li_" + i)[0]; 
                $.data(element, "object", elem); 
            });
            $("#places_ul").html(items).listview('refresh');

        }

    });

}

$(document).on("click", '[id^=cat_li]', function(event, ui) {
    stack.push(event.target.innerText);
})


$(document).on("click", '[id^=place_li]', function(event, ui) {
    var place = $.data(this, "object");
        alert(place.name);
    })
```

var place = $.data(this, "object");
ends up having undefined

Comment: What's the issue, the code looks fine to me.

Comment: How do I manage to have the elem object in the on-click event? I currently dont have it the the on-click event context

Comment: @AAaa -- What do you mean the "elem object", accessing properties of the specific li that was clicked?

Comment: @tymeJV -- 'elem' is the object that $.each function uses to build each li. The way I wrote it, it just takes the elem.name value and puts it in the li tag. But this object has other field which are not relevant when creating the li, but are relevant when the li is clicked. How do I make this object reachble when the li is clicked?

Comment: @AAaa -- Much clearer, thanks for the explanation :D, taking a look at it.

Comment: add them as attributes to `li` or `a` and read them `.on('click'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be to create custom data attributes inside the `li` element to be accessed at a later time. Push the data you need to these custom attributes. Example:

```
items.push('<li id="cat_li_'+i+'" data-custom-cool="' + elem.someData + '"><a href="#places">' + elem.name + '</a></li>');
```

Now, you can pull out the data as you need it with `this` inside your click handler.

```
$(this).data("custom-cool"); //this is equiv to elem.someData .
```

Or, if you have bigger data, you can store the object with the element with $.data:

```
$.each(data, function(i, elem) {
            items.push('<li id="cat_li_'+i+'"><a href="#places">' + elem.name + '</a></li>');
        });
    id.html(items).listview('refresh');
    var element = $("#cat_li_" + i)[0]; //cant use jQ object
    $.data(element, "object", elem); //assign object
});
```

Now your click handler should be able to access the object like so (inside handler):

```
console.log($.data(this, "object").objProperty); //replace objProperty with your property to get.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/vx8Xt/1/ Click on "testdiv" and see the console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the scenario this seems fine because elem.SomeData is a small field. But what if I want to have the entire elem object in the on-click function context? (and lets assume its a very big object)..

Comment: @AAaa -- I'm trying to write something based on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: did you mean to put $.data(element, "object", elem); inside the $.each?

Comment: Yup, it's assigning the object to that specifically created list item.

Comment: The part of getting the object back doesn't seem to work. maybe because of 'this' scope? I edited the original question with the full code.

Comment: Shouldn't be, whats the console say about it? @AAaa

Comment: You're appending to the HTML twice, once inside the .each and once right after. @AAaa -- Remove the second `.html`

Comment: Yep, this was the problem. Now it works. thanks a lot! Can you have a quick comment on the overall pattern of communicating between pages with a stack object and having all pages (which are small by definition) in the same html file?

Comment: Not sure I get what ya mean, like passing data between pages vs a SPA?

Comment: I have multiple logical pages in one html page. I navigate between them with <a href="#somepageid">. if page 1 needs to pass a parameter to page 2, I use a global list into which I push the paramter in the event that triggers the navigation, and pop the parameter in pageInit. This doesnt seem to me as a clean  design (but I've seen this pattern a lot in samples ). So - 1. is this "ok" in javascript/jquery development? 2. How could I do this another way?

Comment: Interesting...seems like an alright way to do it, although I could see that global list getting pretty big depending on the size of the app.  I'm a big fan of Angular right now, so it may be worth looking in to to separate some of the logic out for a cleaner design.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with `id.html(items)`, `.html()` doesn't accept an array.

```
id.html(items.join('')).listview('refresh');
```

Also to fix your other problem, you should use classes instead of ids :

```
function initListByUrl(id, requestUrl) {
    $.getJSON(requestUrl, function(data) {
        var items = []
        $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
                items.push('<li class="cat"><a href="#places">' + elem.name + '</a></li>');
            });
        id.html(items).listview('refresh');
    });
}


$(document).on("click", '.cat a', function(event, ui) {
    console.log(3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like ajax is asynchronous by default, you have two options:

1. You can make the ajax request synchronous by switching the option *async* to false - for more details, see [jQuery.ajax() API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
2. You can save the elem in a global variable and use it in the onclick-handler

Maybe it would also be helpful if you tell us, when the function initListByURL() is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the event binding into the success function, after all item in the list has been attached to Document

```
    success: function(data) {
    var items = []
        $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
            items.push('<li id="cat_li_'+i+'"><a href="#places">' + elem.name + '</a></li>');
        });
        id.html(items).listview('refresh');
        // move your click event handling here 
    }
```

Comment: even if I move it, it won't have elem in its context, only data. elem is in $.each context